# THREE.JS make face normal perpendicular on the face and outside direction

Tags: javascript, three.js

I use `THREE.JS` to create a custom geometry, I create vertices and faces, when I create a face without setting the normal like `new THREE.Face3(a,b,c)` in some faces the normal direction is to inside the geometry, how to make all faces direction is outside the geometry?

Comment: if you create your faces in a counter-clockwise fashion, the normal will be pointing outside

Comment: Thank you, i will try, please put this as answer to make it the right answer.

Comment: make sure it works for you.

Comment: Question is clear and code sample is there. Why votes of closing?

Comment: Thank you it works very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your faces in a counter-clockwise fashion; then the normal will be pointing outwards.